# UML: Composition or Dependency

Tags: dependencies, uml, associations, composition, visio

I have 2 classes `Job` and `Task`. These are the rules:

- Each `Job` has a numeric identifier.
- Each `Job` has 10 corresponding `Task`s.
- Each `Task` has a numeric identifier.
- A `Task` cannot exist without a `Job`.

I am trying to build Class diagram for these 2 classes. Since `Task` cannot live without `Job` so I thought this is a **composition** and this is how I build the Class diagram:

[image]

But now I am confused that if this association is actually **dependency**:

[image]

How can I know in this case if the relationship is **composition** or **dependency**?

---

### UPDATE

I have fixed the **composition (Composite Aggregation)** in the Class diagram as Thomas Kilian suggested:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dependency is the weakest relation between elements. It means that if the element which is depended on is changed it needs some kind of attention in the depending element. E.g. there can be dependencies on enumerations or in a conceptual phase between classes or between packages if they contain associated classes.

A composite aggregation is in first place a strong relation (an association) between two elements. That is one of both is also working with the other side in some way (using attributes or methods). Further the composite aggregation is telling something about object lifetimes. The elements being composed will die once the compositing element is removed. This is merely a construct used for data security e.g. where you need to delete personal records if the person is removed (the car/wheels example does not seem to make so much sense since the wheels still are useable once the car is crashed). Another use could be (nowadays less) storage management.

Two side notes:

- Your drawing is wrong as the filled diamond must attach to the outside and not to the inside of the shape.
- The shared aggregation (hollow diamond) has no defined semantics and should only be used once you define it in a certain domain for a specific use. See p. 112 of the [2.5.1 specs](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/):

  > Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

Comment: Thanks. I dont get your 2nd side note: "The shared aggregation (hollow diamond) has no defined semantics and should only be used once you define it in a certain domain for a specific use." Can you explain with an example?

Comment: See my addition.

Comment: @ThomasKilian there is no hollow diamond in the question

Comment: @srh If you read my answer: "Two side notes". Just in case someone comes across this with the hollow diamond instead.

Comment: @ThomasKilian can you give an example of your 2nd side note? I still dont understand what you meant.

Comment: The hollow diamond is often wrongly used. People think that it's some kind of "loosely coupled composite" which it isn't. My advice is simply: do not use it, as it has no common definition.